# Sort/filter a protected sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, office-for-mac

I want to enable auto filter on a protected sheet in Excel.

When I protect the sheet I make sure to allow sort/filter, but I'm still not allowed to use it.

Solutions online (like https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090419000032AAs5VRR) says I should "Allow Users to Edit Ranges", but I can't find this option anywhere in my Excel 2016.

Below are pictures of what I see in the Protect Sheet dialogue and the Review tab.

[image: Protect Sheet]
[image: Review Tab]

Answer (score 1):

The option to allow users to edit ranges is on the same tab (Review) as the option you use to protect your sheet.

However my experiments indicate you just need to tick the option to allow users to use the AutoFilter. My screenshot below shows you both options in context.

[image: Screenshot of the protect sheet options]

Comment: I don't see those options. Added screenshots to my question showing the world as I see it.

Comment: Excel for windows menus are a little different than for mac. However, selecting Sort and Filter did not help in my case either.  Still looking for a solution.

Comment: You might need to unprotect the sheet first